# async $formatDatabaseJson in Objection.js

Tags: javascript, model, async-await, objection.js

I need to await a function in my $formatDatabaseJson. Im checking the docs (https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/#_s_formatdatabasejson) and seems not possible. Is there any way to do it manually?

```
class Person extends Model {
  async $formatDatabaseJson(json) {
    // Call the super class's implementation.
    json = await super.$formatDatabaseJson(json)
    // await function here
    return json
  }
}
```

Comment: Not the solution but finally I used $beforeInsert, since it support async execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$formatDatabaseJson` is synchronous and cannot be used to call async code. `$beforeInsert`, `$beforeUpdate` and `$afterGet` hooks are async and could be used depending on your use case.